# How to refresh List view content on SwipetoRefresh layout in android?

Tags: android

I have a listview in which onCreate method I am executing URL which gives me list of app which I show in Listview .what I want when I use swipe to refresh I want to clear all list view Items and again execute that URL and fetch Response in Listview.How can I do that..

HERE IS MY CODE:-

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_listing, container, false);//intialize mainLayout
    new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);// execute Url to fetch Deal list from serevr.
}
private void init() {// initialize controls

    mSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
    mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // here I want to clear all items in listview and again execute That Url and fetech new DATA/..
        }
    });
    m_ListView = (ListView) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.dealList);// findind Id of Listview


}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private String DealListing(String url) {// this method POST details of user to server
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        // 1. create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // 2. make POST request to the given URL
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json;
        // 3. build jsonObject
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();// making object of Jsons.
        jsonObject.put("agentCode", m_szMobileNumber);// put mobile number
        jsonObject.put("pin", m_szEncryptedPassword);// put password
        jsonObject.put("recordcount", sz_RecordCount);// put record count
        jsonObject.put("lastcountvalue", sz_LastCount);// put last count
        // 4. convert JSONObject to JSON to String
        json = jsonObject.toString();// convert Json object to string
        if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)// print json request to server
            Log.d(TAG, "Server Request:-" + json);
        // 5. set json to StringEntity
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        // 6. set httpPost Entity
        httpPost.setEntity(se);
        // 7. Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // 9. receive response as inputStream
        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)
            Log.d(TAG, "InputStream:-" + inputStream.toString());
        Log.d(TAG, "Response:-" + httpResponse.toString());

        StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
        if (BuildConfig.klogInfo) {// print server status line code
            Log.d(TAG, "Status Code:-" + statusLine);
        }
        ////Log.d("resp_body", resp_body.toString());
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        // 10. convert inputstream to string
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            // 10. convert inputstream to string
            s_szresult = CJsonsResponse.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            if (BuildConfig.klogInfo)// print server response
                Log.d(TAG, "Server Response:-" + s_szresult);
        } else
            s_szresult = "Did not work!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Response Password:" + m_szEncryptedPassword);
    Log.d(TAG, "Record Count:" + sz_RecordCount);
    Log.d(TAG, "Last count:-" + sz_LastCount);
    // 11. return s_szResult
    return s_szresult;
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
private void getResponse() throws JSONException {// getting response from serevr ..................
    if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Connection Not Available")) {//server based conditions
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "Connection Lost !", getActivity());
    } else if (m_oResponseobject.getString("resultdescription").equalsIgnoreCase("Deal List Not Found")) {// serevr based conditions .....
        CSnackBar.getInstance().showSnackBarError(m_Main.findViewById(R.id.mainLayout), "No more deals available", getActivity());

    }
}

//  sending deal data to server and retreive Deal list......
class CDealDataSent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public CDealAppDatastorage item;// declaring DealAppdataStorage

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// make rogressview Visible while doing background process
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return DealListing(urls[0]);// sending data to server...

    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {// this method Update UI

        m_ProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);// make progressview Gone when background process completes...
        mSwipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
        try {
            m_oResponseobject = new JSONObject(result);// getting response from server
            JSONArray posts = m_oResponseobject.optJSONArray("dealList");// get Deal list in array from response


            for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {// loop for counting deals from server
                JSONObject post = posts.getJSONObject(i);// counting deal based on index
                item = new CDealAppDatastorage();// creating object of DealAppdata storage
                item.setM_szHeaderText(post.getString("dealname"));// get deal name from response
                item.setM_szsubHeaderText(post.getString("dealcode"));// get dealcode from response
                item.setM_szDealValue(post.getString("dealvalue"));// get deal value from response
                item.setM_n_Image(m_n_FormImage[i]);//set Image Index wise(Dummy)
                s_oDataset.add(item);// add all items in ArrayList

            }
            if (!hasLoadMore) {
                // LoadMore button
                btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());// creating button
                btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");// set Text in Button
                btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);// set Background Resource
                btnLoadMore.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);// setting Text appearence of button text
                btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);// set Color of button text
                btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);// set Gravity of button text
                hasLoadMore=true;
            }
            if (!s_oDataset.isEmpty()) {// condition if data in arraylist is not empty
                // Adding Load More button to lisview at bottom
                m_ListView.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);// add footer in listview
                m_oAdapter = new CDealAppListingAdapter(getActivity(), s_oDataset);// create adapter object and add arraylist to adapter
                m_ListView.setAdapter(m_oAdapter);//adding adapter to recyclerview
                m_oAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// notify adapter about changes in List
            } else {
                btnLoadMore.setVisibility(View.GONE);// else Load buttonvisibility set to Gone
            }
            btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {// load more button onclick listener
                    m_n_DefaultRecordCount = 5;// increment of record count by 5 on next load data
                    m_n_DeafalutLastCount = m_n_DeafalutLastCount + 5;// same here.....as above

                    sz_RecordCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DefaultRecordCount);// convert int value to string
                    sz_LastCount = String.valueOf(m_n_DeafalutLastCount);// convert int value to string /////
                    new DealNext().execute(m_DealListingURL);// POST DATA TO SERVER TO LOAD MORE DATA......
                }
            });

            getResponse();// get response from server....
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import some library. Maybe you can watch this: https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView

Comment: and why do you need other library  while `SwipeRefreshLayout` is available in android API.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like this

```
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        m_Main = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deal_listing, container, false);//intialize mainLayout
        new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);// execute Url to fetch Deal list from serevr.
    }
    private void init() {// initialize controls

        mSwipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) m_Main.findViewById(R.id.activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout);
        mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
              m_ListView.removeFooterView(loadMoreButton);  // call this
              s_oDataset.clear();
              new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);// execute Url to fetch Deal list from serevr.
            }
        });
```

Comment: and where to remove swipe to refresh

Comment: but here is problem I have a load more button in below listview after doing your code it works fine but double the loadmore button

Comment: to remove swipe to refresh call  mSwipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);  inside onRefresh() method

Comment: as I m not understand

Comment: Declare one member Variable:-
 private boolean mIsLoadMoreButtonExist; and in 
onPostExecute(){ 

if(!mIsLoadMoreButtonExist){ then write your code of creating Button ....... ....... then set this --> mIsLoadMoreButtonExist=true; 
}

Comment: hey this every time take space of loadmore button width and height

Comment: mSwipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
     s_oDataset.clear();
     new CDealDataSent().execute(m_DealListingURL);
    }
   });

Comment: if (!hasLoadMore) {
     // LoadMore button
     btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());// creating button
     btnLoadMore.setText("LOAD MORE DEALS");// set Text in Button
     btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_boarder);// set Background Resource
     btnLoadMore.setTextAppearance(getActivity(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Small);// setting Text appearence of button text
     btnLoadMore.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);// set Color of button text
     btnLoadMore.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);// set Gravity of button text
     hasLoadMore=true;
    }

Comment: private boolean hasLoadMore;

Comment: Oh!! that is bcoz you are adding list view footer, you do one thing remove that boolean  and see my updated answer

Comment: You got what i said??!!